# How to write Album Artist ID3 tag using lame?

Tags: id3, lame

Lame doesn't have a command line option to record the ID3 metadata of the "Album Artist". How to do it?

Comment: Are you dependent on lame?

Comment: @A.B.: I want to do it during the encoding process. I don't want an extra step just to fix the metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Album artist is a non standardized ID3 tag. A lot of popular music players, like iTunes and Windows Media Player, understand the the TPE2 as the album artist.

So you must use something like:

```
--tv TPE2=%albumartist%
```

Answer (score 6):

Lame does have ID tags in commandline form. Use them when you are encoding with lame. To tag existing files you may be better served using another method. Refer to [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lame) by running `man lame` or even `lame -?` provides good info.

```
lame -?

  ID3 tag options:
--tt <title>    audio/song title (max 30 chars for version 1 tag)
--ta <artist>   audio/song artist (max 30 chars for version 1 tag)
--tl <album>    audio/song album (max 30 chars for version 1 tag)
--ty <year>     audio/song year of issue (1 to 9999)
--tc <comment>  user-defined text (max 30 chars for v1 tag, 28 for v1.1)
--tn <track[/total]>   audio/song track number and (optionally) the total
                       number of tracks on the original recording. (track
                       and total each 1 to 255. just the track number
                       creates v1.1 tag, providing a total forces v2.0).
--tg <genre>    audio/song genre (name or number in list)
--ti <file>     audio/song albumArt (jpeg/png/gif file, v2.3 tag)
--tv <id=value> user-defined frame specified by id and value (v2.3 tag)
--add-id3v2     force addition of version 2 tag
--id3v1-only    add only a version 1 tag
--id3v2-only    add only a version 2 tag
--id3v2-utf16   add following options in unicode text encoding
--id3v2-latin1  add following options in latin-1 text encoding
--space-id3v1   pad version 1 tag with spaces instead of nulls
--pad-id3v2     same as '--pad-id3v2-size 128'
--pad-id3v2-size <value> adds version 2 tag, pad with extra <value> bytes
--genre-list    print alphabetically sorted ID3 genre list and exit
--ignore-tag-errors  ignore errors in values passed for tags

Note: A version 2 tag will NOT be added unless one of the input fields
won't fit in a version 1 tag (e.g. the title string is longer than 30
characters), or the '--add-id3v2' or '--id3v2-only' options are used,
or output is redirected to stdout.
```

Use it like this from a script I run:

```
        lame  --vbr-new --preset standard --tt "${tt}" --ta "${ta}" --tl "${tl}" --ty "${ty}" --tn "${tn}" --tg "${tg}" --add-id3v2 infile.wav outfile.mp3
```

Comment: That's an interesting caveat, @John Mehorter: `To tag existing files you may be better served using another method.` I'm finding that to be true, specifically because Lame re-encodes the entire file merely to add a tag. So, while `lame` may be ideal for tagging while encoding, a tool like `mid3v2` ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131660 ) is much better suited to tagging existing files.